# Glide not loading images from IP url Connection reset Socket exception

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-glide, socketexception

Help with glide, I have a VDS server that does not have a domain, but I receive JSON data from the API from it, but I don’t understand when I want to load an image on the screen using Glide, it gives an error that there is `SocketException. Connection reset`. Is there any way to get around this? I am loading an image from `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1901/image/image.webp`

I tried other libraries like Picasso and URL.openconnection()

I tried load image from browser this successfullly working. only with glide no work!!!

Comment: There is some steps you should test first...
Does your image URL (http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1901/image/image.webp) load on a web page?
Did you try loading a public image link to ensure your code works fine? (for example, get a Google image URL and load it on your app with Glide)
Finally can you add a snapshot of your code and error?
It will be more debuggable if your code sample is added to your question.

Comment: Just to double check. you have http connections enabled, right? Not HTTPS